# how to show all of user's properties in django 

Tags: python, django

this is my code :

```
def callback(req):
 token = req.session.get('token', None)
 if not token:
  return render_to_response('callback.html', {
   'token': True
  })
 token = oauth.OAuthToken.from_string(token)
 if token.key != req.GET.get('oauth_token', 'no-token'):
  return render_to_response('callback.html', {
   'mismatch': True
  })
 token = get_authorized_token(token)

 # Actually login
 obj = is_authorized(token)
 if obj is None:
  return render_to_response('callback.html', {
   'username': True
  })
 try: user = User.objects.get(username=obj['screen_name'])
 except: user = User(username=obj['screen_name'])

 user.oauth_token = token.key
 user.oauth_token_secret = token.secret
 user.save()
 req.session['user_id'] = user.id
 del req.session['token']

 s = ''.join('%s: %s </br>' % (a, getattr(user, a)) for a in dir(user))
 return HttpResponse(s)
```

and i want use

```
s = ''.join('%s: %s </br>' % (a, getattr(user, a)) for a in dir(user))
return HttpResponse(s)
```

to show the user's properties  ,

but i get a error :

```
AttributeError at /twitter/login/callback/

Manager isn't accessible via User instances
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should troubleshoot by using a for loop and finding out where the problem is!

I looped through the `User` object, and found it doesn't like `getattr(user, '_base_manager')` or `getattr(user, 'objects')`

Do you just want the fields, or really all of the python code associated with the user object?

**If you just want the fields defined in models.py:**

```
for field in user._Meta.fields:
    print '%s: %s' % (field.name, field.value_to_string(user))
```

**if you want all the magic that dir does**
Just do a normal for loop. List comprehensions are not going to catch exceptions any easier.

```
for attr in dir(user):
    try:
        print '%s: %s' % (attr, getattr(user, attr))
    except Exception, e:
        print '%s: %s' % (attr, e)
```

**If you love your list comprehensions that much**

```
def no_exception_getattr(user, attr):
    try: 
        return getattr(user, attr)
    except Exception, e: 
        return e

''.join(['%s: %s' % (x, no_exception_getattr(user, x)) for x in dir(user)])
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way would be to add an introspective method to your model.

see [Django templates: loop through and print all available properties of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217478/django-templates-loop-through-and-print-all-available-properties-of-an-object)

and also [Iterate over model instance field names and values in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/django-iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template)