# How can I loop through all the properties of an python object in django templates

Tags: python, django

I have django template and I get a some object.
I want apply for in cycle for all atributes this object.

```
    {% for point in Object %}
        <h1>{{ Object[point] }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: who upvoted this question? there are like 100 answers out there explaining what you need to do

Comment: Pretty certain this is just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217478/django-templates-loop-through-and-print-all-available-properties-of-an-object

Comment: @hansTheFranz maybe say at least one?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in the template.
One solution is to convert your object in a dictionary in the view with `object.__dict__` and then iterate over it with:

```
{% for attr, value in object_dict.items %}
    {{ attr }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

As py_dude suggests, you can discard attributes starting with underscores to keep your actual attributes.

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for k, v in Object.__dict__.items() %}
    {% if not k.startswith("_") %}
        <h1>{{ v }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This wont' work, you can't use `__dict__` in a template.