# How do I remove default whitespace in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to list a series of items separated by commas.

But if an item after the first doesnt exist, I don't want the comma or item to appear.

So I've implemented this:

```
<em>{{object.item1|default_if_none:""}}</em>
        {% if object.item2 %}
            <em>, {{object.item2|default_if_none:""}},</em>
        {% endif %}
            <em>{{object.item3|default_if_none:""}}</em>
```

If object.item2 exists, it'll put a whitespace after item1--before the comma. 
When it displays, it'll look something like:
"I_am_item_one , I_am_item_two, Item_three"

What's the best way to fix this?

edit: is it possible to for-loop through an object's properties?
`{% for property in object.property %}` or similar..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to loop over objects and their properties in a template. You could look into either passing the data into the template as a dictionary/list or creating a model method (as done in this answer: [Django templates: loop through and print all available properties of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217478/django-templates-loop-through-and-print-all-available-properties-of-an-object))

Once your data is iterable, you could use the following code to decide when to add a comma. I am not entirely clear if you want a comma between each item or only after the first item, so here are two options.

This will only add a comma on the first entry

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    <em>{{ item }}</em>{% if forloop.first %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor}
```

This will add a comma after each item except the last one

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    <em>{{ item }}</em>{% if not forloop.last%}, {% endif %}
{% endfor}
```

It is probably fairly clear, but you can use `forloop.first` to detect when you are on your first item and `forloop.last` to detect when you are on the last item of a loop.