# Object is not iterable in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

When i try to iterate object from database in Django, It give me an error. I dont know really why. It give me precisely this error: "'Clovek' object is not iterable"

```
user=request.user
user=Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)
user=user[0]
prvni_prihlaseni=False
first=True
for i in user:
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable
the object user is not iterable and it make completly sense.
the user, the list not the object (change that naming), is iterable (a list).

Comment: Question doesn't reflect true intentions / poor research was done. "but i want to iterate only one user, and every variable in that object, Because i want to know if any variable in object is blank or not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments, and figuring out what you wanted to do, found this, to iterate over a model's fields:

> model._meta.get_all_field_names() will give you all the model's field
>   names, then you can use model._meta.get_field() to work your way to
>   the verbose name, and getattr() to get the value from the model.

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/django-iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot iterate a model object unless you defined `__iter__` in the model.

Do you mean iterate the queryset returned by `Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)`? Then, I think it's a typo:

```
user = request.user
users = Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)
#   ^      v
user = users[0]
prvni_prihlaseni=False
first=True
for i in users:
#            ^
```

Comment: Its not a typo, because from a queryset Its only One object and I want to iterate every variable in that object

Comment: @user2771714, `every variable`? What's that mean? Do you want to iterate values of all fields?

Comment: yes, but i already figure it out through usera._meta.get_all_field_names() and getattr()

Comment: @user2771714, Did you try `Clovek.objects.all()[:1].values()` or `Clovek.objects.all()[:1].values_list()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
user=Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)
user=user[0]
```

just set a different variable name. Don't use the same for both.

You cannot loop over `user`. the variable user in your code is set to user[0] which is not iterable. You need to loop over the query set `Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)` so that it prints the result.

This will work:

```
users = Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)
for i in users:
    print i
```

This won't work:

```
users = Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)
user = users[0]
for i in user: # user is not an iterable but users is. 
    print i
```

An example:

```
users = Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)
# in case there's only 1 result.
# user = users[0]
# you can access any of its field
# user.id, user.whatever

# in case there's more than 1:
for i in users:
    print i.id
```

Comment: even if i change the name of the variable, It doesnt work. user=request.user
 usera=Clovek.objects.all().filter(user=user)
 users=usera[0]
 prvni_prihlaseni=False
 first=True
 for i in users:

Comment: but i want to iterate only one user, and every variable in that object, Because i want to know if any variable in object is blank or not

Comment: You can access any field like this `users[0].field` or `user.field` if `user=users[0]`. No need to loop.