# I have a list containg objects which in turn consists some test parameters. How to access those parameters?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this list of objects and I need to access the individual parameters inside a particular object. Any help?

```
[object1,object2,object3,object4,object5,object6]
```

When I try iterating through for loop it says Objects are not iterable

```
values[]
self.values=list(TestParameters.objects.filter(id=1))

for x in self.values:
   for y in x:
      print y
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
values=[TestParameters.objects.filter(id = 1)]
for x in values:
    for y in x:
        print y
```

If you want to iterate over Model instances 
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template)

Comment: Its printing those objects multiple times instead of going inside those objects and printing the elements within

Comment: It will print the column representing the object. If you want to iterate the object parameters then please see the reference I provided.

Comment: I will go through it and let you know. Thanks for sharing