# Looping over a model object fields in a view

Tags: python, django, view, model

I have a model like below. I would like to loop over all the fields inside a view to get field name and value of the field in the corresponding object.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over model instance field names and values in template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template)

Comment: That question is related to template. Here, I am looking for looping with in a view @wpercy

Comment: It answers the same question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431104/5525068) helped me
The idea is you can turn a model object into a dict and then iterate over the dict

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
...
result = Company.objects.get(id=7)
resultDict = model_to_dict(result)
for key, value in resultDict.items():
  print(f'key: {key} - value: {value}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Model `_meta` API. In this case you want the `get_fields` method:

```
Company._meta.get_fields()
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model

Comment: Here, I am looking for both field name and the value of that field in an object.

Comment: After getting all the names you can retrieve the value of that field for an specific instance like this: `getattr(activity_instance, field_name)`.

Comment: `Company._meta.get_fields()` gives a tuple of all fields (types and **names**). Is it possible to **only** get the field names and pass it to a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try to serialize the `QuerySet`:

```
from django.core import serializers
from .models import YourModel

# inside the view
...
object_list = serializers.serialize("python", YourModel.objects.all())

for object in object_list:
    for field_name, field_value in object['fields'].items():
        print field_name, field_value
```