# Automatically get name of the column with for loop in django template

Tags: python, django, for-loop, templates

I would like to automatically retrieve the name of the column with a for loop.
If I know the name of the columns I can write the template in this way:

```
<ul>
{% for co in team %}
    <li>{{ co.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ co.team}}</li>
    <li>{{ co.sport}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But in my present case, I do not know the names of the columns of my table. How can I display them?

Thank you

Comment: I think you should write this logic in the *view*, not in the template. The expresiveness of Django templates has been restricted (deliberately) to avoid people writing such behavior in a template.

Comment: check this answer ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170243/8150371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the fields of a model with:

```
fields = Model._meta.get_fields()
```

This is a tuple of [**`Field`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L45) objects. These `Field` objects have a `name` attribute, so we can obtain the field names with:

```
from operator import attrgetter

field_names = map(attrgetter('name'), Model._meta.get_fields())
```

In case we do not know what the model is, we can obtain a reference to the model of a model instance with `type(..)`:

```
fields = type(some_instance)._meta.get_fields()
```

All this logic however does not really belong in the Django template, but in the view (by design, Django templates are a bit restrictive to prevent writing *business logic* in the template). We can thus pass a list of field names to the template:

```
def some_view(request):
    teams = Team.objects.all()
    field_names = [f.name for f in Team._meta.get_fields()]
    return render(request, 'some_template.html',
        {'teams': teams, 'field_names': field_names}
    )
```

If you however want to print the values of these teams, then this will still not work, since we can not easily get an *arbitrary* attribute in a template. Then we can again shift some processing to the view:

```
from operator import attregetter

def some_view(request):
    teams = Team.objects.all()
    field_names = [f.name for f in Team._meta.get_fields()]
    atgetters = [attrgetter(fn) for fn in field_names]
    rows = [[ag(team) for ag in atgetters] for team in teams]
    return render(request, 'some_template.html',
        {'teams': teams, 'field_names': field_names, 'data': data}
    )
```

So here `data` is a list containing lists, such that `data[i][j]` contains the value for a field with name `field_name[j]` for `teams[i]`.