# Django debugging: how to pretty print an object in template

Tags: django

In Django i want to know how to see the full objects which may have nested objects like model, formset etc in template as html or `<pre>` element

Is it possible.

Because it will help me to debug and check the results.

Comment: Have a look at [Iterate over model instance field names and values in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228)

Comment: thats for model class. will it work for any class

Answer (score 4):

I just came up on that question that hasn't the right answer which is using the special built-in template filter `pprint`.

```
# in your template

{{ my_value | pprint }}
```

As said in the [docstring](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#pprint), it helps, really.