# How can I display certain fields of a django model in a template?

Tags: django

I would like to display certain fields for all objects of a model in a table. And I also want to render the url property of some FileFields, which are part of that model.

So, I got models with obj_data = ThatObject.objects.only('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

But I do not know how to access everything in the template.
I could say {% for single_object in obj_data %}, but I cannot iterate over the fields of single_object. How can I do that?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template

Comment: Thanks. I am somewhat confused that there is no simple option to iterate over a model. I do not know about getattr and so, but I guess I am about to find out.